# vDSP_fft_zrip understanding the transformed DSPSplitComplex content

Tags: signal-processing, fft, vdsp

Assuming "A" is a real vector packed (with vDSP_ctoz) in the proper way, doing:

```
vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &A, 1, FFT_LENGTH_LOG2, FFT_FORWARD);
```

Will transform my real content to it's frequency representation.

What do then the following values represents ?:

```
A.realp[0];
A.imagp[0];

A.realp[i];
A.imagp[i];

A.realp[N-1];
A.imagp[N-1];
```

Actually I'm wondering where is the DC and Nyquist components stored. Also is the A.imagp[j] the imaginary part of A.realp[j] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let **H** be the vector that is the mathematical result of the FFT, so that H<sub>k</sub> is the k<sup>th</sup> element of the vector. H<sub>0</sub> is the DC component, and H<sub>N/2</sub> is the Nyquist component. Then:

`A.realp[0]` contains H<sub>0</sub>.

`A.imagp[0]` contains H<sub>N/2</sub>.

For 0 < k < N/2, `A.realp[k]` and `A.imagp[k]` combined contain H<sub>k</sub>. Specifically, `A.realp[k]` contains the real part of H<sub>k</sub>, and `A.imagp[k]` contains the imaginary part of H<sub>k</sub>. Equivalently, H<sub>k</sub> = `A.realp[k]` + *i* • `A.imagp[k]`.

Some documentation about the vDSP FFTs is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html).